# AppArmor: How to apply different profiles for same executable according to UID?

Tags: apparmor

I'd like to jail my (chrooted) php-fpm pool workers using *AppArmor*. As each pool runs under a separate UID, I'd like to apply different AppArmor profiles for the workers so that a worker process can only access files in its own pool's document root, not the other pools' roots.

The problem is that all the php-fpm workers run the same binary (*/usr/sbin/php5-fpm*), so a profile like

```
/usr/sbin/php5-fpm {
    (...)
}
```

would be applied to all instances, i.e. all pool workers.

A possible solution for my specific issue could be the use of `owner` conditional rules for the document root paths, but I'm wondering if there is generally no way to have different profiles for multiple instances of the same binary with *AppArmor*.